# implode(): Invalid arguments passed laravel

Tags: php, laravel, implode

I am having some difficulty solving this problem, where I keep on getting this error: implode(): Invalid arguments passed when I try to update my data.

Information: I am trying to update this 3 tables, users, schools and hobbys. Where user can have many school and user can have many hobby.

Problem: When I try to update user or school data, I will get an error "implode(): Invalid arguments passed" but when I try to update hobby data, it was successful.

But if I were to remove the function for hobby data, I am able to edit both the user or school data.

What I want is to be able to update all my data

HomeController:

```
//update for personal_info
    public function edit($id){
        $object = user::find($id);

        return view('edit', compact('object'));

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $object = user::find($id);
        $object->Name = $request->input('Name');
        $object->update();

        return redirect('/home');
    }


    //update for Schools table
    public function edit1($id){
      $object2 = school::find($id);
       return view('edit1', compact('object2'));

    }
    public function update1(Request $request, $id){
        $object2 = school::find($id);
        $test = array();
    $test['School'] = implode(' , ', $request->School);
    $test['SDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->SDate);
    $test['EDate'] = implode(' , ', $request->EDate);
        $object2->update($test);
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    //error start here after putting this whole thing in. (I tried putting it into another separate controller but the error still continues)
            public function edit2($id){
      $object3 = hobby::find($id);
       return view('edit2', compact('object3'));

    }
    public function update2(Request $request, $id){
        $object3 = hobby::find($id);
    $test2 = array();
    $test2['computer_game'] = implode(' , ', $request->computer_game);
    $test2['reading_book'] = implode(' , ', $request->reading_book);
        $object3->update($test2);
        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

test.blade.php (show all the user and other information related to him)

```
<h1>User Information</h1>
@foreach ($data as $object)
    <b>Name: </b>{{ $object->Name }}<br><br>
<a href="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id.'/edit') }}">Edit</a>
<h1>School information</h1>

    @foreach ($object->schools as $object2)
    <b>School: </b>{{ $object2->School }}<br><br>
    <b>Start Date: </b>{{ $object2->SDate }}<br><br>
    <b>End Date: </b>{{ $object2->EDate }}<br><br>
    <a href="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object2->id.'/edit1') }}">Edit</a>

<h1>Hobbies</h1>
 @foreach ($object->hobbys as $object3)
    <b>hobby: </b>{{ $object3->computer_game }}<br><br>
    <b>sport: </b>{{ $object3->reading_book }}<br><br>
    <a href="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object3->id.'/edit2') }}">Edit</a>
```

edit.blade.php (edit page for user)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object->id) }}">
  {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2">Name of user:</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{ $object->Name }}" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
    </div>
```

edit1.blade.php (for school, similar to edit2, uses html table, can add row to add number of school user attended)

```
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object2->id) }}">
          {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
          {{ csrf_field() }}
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr >
                        <th class="text-center">
              #
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Name of School/University/Professional Institute:
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Start Date:
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              End Date:
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>
            1
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name='School[]' class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="date" name='SDate[]' class="form-control"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="date" name='EDate[]' class="form-control"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
```

edit2.blade.php (html table where user can add row to add more info about what are his hobby)

```
     <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user/show/'.$object3->id) }}">
              {{ method_field('PUT')  }}
              {{ csrf_field() }}
     <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
            <thead>
              <tr >
                            <th class="text-center">
                  #
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                  Sports:
                </th>
                <th class="text-center">
                  Books read:
                </th>
                              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id='addr0'>
                <td>
                1
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name='computer_game[]' class="form-control"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name='reading_book[]' class="form-control"/>
                </td>
                              </tr>
                        <tr id='addr1'></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
```

Comment: what actually is the error?

Comment: I keep getting this error "implode(): Invalid arguments passed" whenever I try to edit my data

Comment: could you paste the error...

Comment: I edited my question already

Comment: I don't see any error logs

Comment: weird, never mind, I keep getting this error "implode(): Invalid arguments passed " @BasheerAhmedKharoti

Comment: There are three implode statements. Just try commenting one by one and see which one causes the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157119/discussion-between-blastme-and-basheer-ahmed-kharoti).

Comment: @BasheerAhmadKharoti, I have updated my question already could you take a lot tks

Answer (score 1):

Please check on this line

```
$test2['hobby] = implode(' , ', $request->hobby);
```

Comment: I have already updated it still get the same error, it was some typo when I was typing it in just now

Comment: Make sure that the second parameter is an array.

Comment: I have used $test2= array(); to make sure it becomes an array

Comment: I am able to update it successfully but personal_infos and user_infos will then get the error "implode(): Invalid arguments passed" and if I were to remove user_info1s, personal_infos and user_infos can be updated

Comment: Is $request->School an array?

Comment: Ya, user_infos and user_info1s are both using array.

Comment: please double check $request->School, $request->SDate & $request->EDate if it's an array. I think the error comes from those object properties because implode only accept array on the second parameter.

Comment: Yes, I had checked that they are arrays through the use of dd($request->all()); and I got something like this, 

array:4 [▼ 
 "_method" => "PUT" 
 "_token" => "SoOsHkbd7fnih9XKskgq8SSgZ8yMnqmxqPlhWL3N" 
 "hobby" => array:1 [▼ 
 0 => "lasdka" 
 ] 
 "sport" => array:1 [▼ 
 0 => "bbgy" 
 ] 
 ]

Comment: Try dd($request->School); because you are not passing the ($request->all()); on the implode function

Comment: erm I keep getting an error "implode(): Invalid arguments passed"when I try to put the dd

Comment: use exit;
example:
dd($request->School);exit;

Comment: Ok finally got it, it showed me this, array:1 [▼
  0 => "gdb"
]   But I have to put it near the user_info1s function and not user_infos function (which is under the school)

Answer (score 0):

In method :

```
public function update2(Request $request, $id){
    $object3 = user_info1::find($id);
    $test2 = array();
    $test2['From'] = implode(' , ', $request->From);
    $test2['To'] = implode(' , ', $request->To);
    $test2['hobby] = implode(' , ', $request->hobby);
    $test2['sport'] = implode(' , ', $request->sport);
    $object3->update($test2);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

use this

```
$test2['hobby'] = implode(' , ', $request->hobby);
```

instead this

```
$test2['hobby] = implode(' , ', $request->hobby);
```